# Поднять сайдбар над товарами в мобильной версии

Tags: css, wordpress

Всем привет! 
Во-первых спасибо за такой хороший информационный ресурс, низкий поклон!)
Мне нужна помощь, как переместить сайдбар с фильтрами только на мобильной версии и разместить над товарами на странице магазина WC (использую связку WP+WP_Ocean+WC), ссылка на страницу: https://idcrf.ru/shop/

Буду очень признателен)

Comment: Куда переместить?

Comment: На рисунке стрелочками покажи что хочешь сделать.